# How to specify a custom action on Java exception in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, ide

I'm working in Java with Eclipse (Luna) and I would like to specify what action happens whenever my project throws an exception.  In other words, anytime an error happens and Eclipse prints a stack trace to the console, I would like to run my own code to print the stack trace in my own debug window or save to a text file, for example.

I'm not sure if this is a problem for my java project (maybe by overriding printStackTrace()?) or for the IDE itself (through some setting, etc.)  Either way it doesn't really matter since its just a debug feature and would be removed before I export anything public.

Thanks for your help

EDIT: To clarify, I'm not talking about exceptions only from a specific line/class.  I'm familiar with try-catch blocks.  What I want is to preform an action any time any exception or error happens anywhere in my code, even if there is a typo and my project wont compile.

Comment: You need to `catch(Exception e)` and write the code inside catch block, appears from your description that its a `RuntimeException` that is being thrown in your code.

Comment: If u are familiar with try and catch block... then you must be knowing that if you want to perform specific action on any exception or error you need to define them and then call them when you catch those exceptions in specific catch block!.. For errors that occur when your project does not complie... you cant do anything.. coz your actions will still be in project... so just look or log the System.out or System.err to file to view

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: **You cannot have your own debug window in IDE**

If you want to log some of your exceptions to some file wherein latter on you can see, so its time you use **log4j**.
Start with this simple [example](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/).

You will find ample on google :)